# dismiss share extension custom viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, share, viewcontroller

I am trying to create a custom view controller to be used with a share extension. Everything works, but I don't know how to dismiss the custom view controller.  Basically I launch my share extension from safari and want to completely dismiss this and return back to the safari view. I know this should not be hard, but I am new to share extensions.  Below is my base code.  Thanks.  Bob

```
//
//  ShareViewController.swift
//  ShareExtension


import UIKit
import Social
import MobileCoreServices

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
    private var url: NSURL?


    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("back button pressed")

       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad()  {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    private func getURL() {
        let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as! NSExtensionItem
        let itemProvider = extensionItem.attachments?.first as! NSItemProvider
        let propertyList = String(kUTTypePropertyList)
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(propertyList) {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: propertyList, options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) -> Void in
                guard let dictionary = item as? NSDictionary else { return }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    if let results = dictionary[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey] as? NSDictionary,
                        let urlString = results["URL"] as? String,
                        let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
                        self.url = url
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the bug is fixed

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should end your sharing extensions work with one of these two calls:

```
self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems(nil, completionHandler: nil)

self.extensionContext!.cancelRequestWithError(NSError())
```

[Apples share extension docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html)

updated for swift 4:

```
self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)

self.extensionContext!.cancelRequest(withError:NSError())
```

Comment: For Xcode 8.3 I had to modify to: self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil) - but that works!  Thanks.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update code for swift 3, your are right

Comment: @OliverM after adding this lines still is not working

Comment: The key is to call completeRequestReturningItems before dismissing the custom view controller

Comment: `NSError()` crashes on runtime (swift5). You should return `NSError(domain: "com.domain.name", code: 0, userInfo: nil)` instead

Comment: **DO NOT** pass an empty NSError() instance to `cancelRequest` method or it will lead to EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION crash. You can use main bundle's identifier as a domain: `NSError(domain: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, code: 0)`

Answer (score 5):

For those who are trying to do this from viewDidLoad, you need to set a small timer, otherwise it won't work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.didSelectPost), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
  }
```