# Share extension ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, share, share-extension

I have created a share extension with some buttons in it and inherited that extension with `UIViewcontroller`. when I create `@IBAction` of those `UIButtons` it never gets called on clicking the button.

```
import UIKit
import Social

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    
//    override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
//        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
//        return true
//    }
//
//    override func didSelectPost() {
//        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.
//    
//        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
//        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
//    }
//
//    override func configurationItems() -> [Any]! {
//        // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
//        return []
//    }

    @IBAction func btnBackClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func btnCancleClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func btnSaveClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you connected the buttons in Interface Builder? Is the ViewController in IB set to ShareViewController?

Comment: yes i did all of this still no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your button actions are being called, just that calling `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` will not actually dismiss your share extension.

With reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43671432/10953499), you should be using:

`self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)`

OR

`self.extensionContext!.cancelRequest(withError:NSError(domain: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, code: 0))`